# Encontrar amigos que confirmaram um evento na graph_api

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook

Andei pesquisando por um tempo como fazer este tipo de requisição sem utilizar FQL (visto que FQL está obsoleto). O único método que realmente encontrei que funciona é pegar a lista de pessoas que estão confirmadas no evento `/{event-id}/attending` e depois pegar a lista de amigos do usuário e verificar isto dentro do servidor/aplicação. Queria deixar este processamento para o servidor do Facebook.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ou já fez algo parecido?